# Can I display a Dataframe in Output form from within a while loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, while-loop

I am trying to write a small python program to manage tables within a sql db. One of my functions is designed to query the db, and store it in a dataframe, then display the dataframe in output format. This function runs fine on its own, but when it is placed in a while loop, it wont display the output because the loop is still running.

Running this below will output the df in the usual clean dataframe format.

```
def show_table(x,k={}):
    mydb=connect(k.get("a_p"), k.get("h"), k.get("u"), k.get("p"), k.get("db"))
    try:
        quack = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM '+str(x), mydb)
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print("An error occured: {}".format(e))
    finally:
        if (mydb.is_connected()):
            mydb.close()
    return quack
show_table(stock_main,sql)
```

When placed in my while loop, it will not output.

```
i=True
while i != "":
    i = input("select table")
    if i in tables:
        show_table(i,sql)
    else:
        print(False)
```

If I assign a variable to show_table, then print it, it will print out the table but not in the clean dataframe output format and then continue through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [3,4,5]})
i = 0
while i!=2:
    i+=1
    display(HTML(df.to_html()))
```